# filtering or subsetting a dataframe does not include all values

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, dplyr, subset

I have a dataframe and I'm trying to subset it based on the column `ID`, but because the `ID` values are repeated, not all values are included in the output.

Example:

```
values <- sample(1:100, 2520, replace=TRUE)
ID <- rep(c(1:21), times = 120) #21 unique IDs, each repeated 120 times
df <- data.frame(values, ID)


df_sub <- df %>% dplyr::filter(ID == c(1,2,5,7,9))
```

It's subsetting by `ID` correctly, but I am only getting 24 rows for each `ID` and not the 120 I am expecting.

`length(df_sub$ID)` = 120 and should be 600.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `%in%` instead of `==` as `==` is elementwise operator and can only with a single element or the lengths shsould be same on the lhs and rhs of `==`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    dplyr::filter(ID %in% c(1,2,5,7,9))
```